# Redux-toolkit deeply nested flatmapped data not updating state

Tags: react-redux, redux-toolkit, immer.js

I have deeply nested data, and need to update some deeply nested child. Currently I do it by flatmapping the two upper level lists, then searching in all the possible tasks, and then mutating the task by calling the init function.

```
const tasks = state.data.flatMap((p) => p.hierarchyLines).flatMap((h) => h?.tasks);
const task = tasks.find((t) => t?.id === payload.id);
task?.init(payload);
```

task.init(data: any):

```
this.id = _data["id"];
this.start = _data["start"] ? new Date(_data["start"].toString()) : <any>undefined;
this.deadline = _data["deadline"] ? new Date(_data["deadline"].toString()) : <any>undefined;
...
```

This does not work, any advice on why it is not updating the state?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I directly modify a component's state, really?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37755997/why-cant-i-directly-modify-a-components-state-really)

Comment: @Ergis : I guess, `redux-toolkit` tag is worth attention here, since it has [Immer](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/) under the hood that _translates_ state mutations into immutable updates.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov Didn't know about that actually. So thanks for the notice :)

Comment: As @YevgenGorbunkov rightly said, it's the immerjs tag that's important (I guess)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone should ever run into a similiar issue. The problem was that immer does not handle classes well.
https://immerjs.github.io/immer/complex-objects

For me the solution was copying the state first, then mutating it, and then returning the copy as described here: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/immer-reducers#immer-usage-patterns

```
    builder.addCase(fetch.fulfilled, (state, { payload }) => {
      const stateCopy = _.cloneDeep(state);
      stateCopy.loading = false;
      const tasks = stateCopy.data.flatMap((p) => p.hierarchyLines).flatMap((h) => h?.tasks);
      const task = tasks.find((t) => t?.id === payload.id);
      task?.init(payload);
      return stateCopy;
    });
```